# How to properly use the language files in joomla

Tags: joomla, joomla2.5, joomla-extensions

As far as i could dig in thought google, i found something like:

```
<languages>
<language tag="en-GB">en-GB.whatever.ini</language>
<language tag="en-GB">en-GB.whatever.sys.ini</language>
</languages>
```

From here some question:

1. Can i use it without tag and somehow specify to use with the default system language
2. What is the difference between `whatever.ini` and `whatever.sys.ini`
3. Do I have something else to write to xml or those 4 lines uploads and runs languages

Answer (score 4):

1. The `tag="en-GB"` is required.
2. `.ini` contains ALL the translations including the description for an extension when it it opened up in the Module or plugin Manager....`sys.ini` is used to define the description of the extension upon installation.
3. The code you provided in the XML is fine ;)

Comment: not within the XML unfortunately. If this module is for supposed to be available to the public, then the majority of people will use en-GB. If they don't, they can translate it themselves.

Comment: You can make another language default just by using another language code though! - It is the tag that is required not which language that goes inside the tag - Although @Lodder is correct in saying that most people on Joomla will use en-GB