# What is the difference between the Joomla component language files "sys.ini" and "ini"?

Tags: joomla

While creating a component, I saw two language files in Joomla's component directory structure: `.ini` and `sys.ini`. What is the difference?

Comment: check this answer- http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12821179/how-to-properly-use-the-language-files-in-joomla/12821345#12821345

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `.sys.ini` file is used to translate the description of the extension upon installaion, where as the `.ini` file is used to translate the remaining strings and the description when viewing your extension in the Joomla backend.

Answer (score 7):

While @Lodder is essentially correct the `sys.ini` files actually have 3 roles.

1. It provides the translation strings for the installation/updating process as well as the de-installation process.
2. From 1.6+ it replaces [the old `extension.menu.ini` for component menu items](http://docs.joomla.org/Translating_entries_in_the_Components_menu).
3. It is used by various Joomla managers to display the translated name of your extension.

You can find that in the section on `sys.ini` in the [Joomla Docs](http://docs.joomla.org/) article on [Adapting a Joomla 1.5 Extension](http://docs.joomla.org/Adapting_a_Joomla_1.5_extension_to_Joomla_1.6#sys.ini_Language_Translation_File)

You can also find out more in the article [International Enhancements for Version 1.6](http://docs.joomla.org/International_Enhancements_for_Version_1.6) which also has a section on [The new sys.ini](http://docs.joomla.org/International_Enhancements_for_Version_1.6#The_new_.sys.ini)